# Kivy on Android crashing when a special character is inserted

Tags: python, kivy

I can successfully launch a Kivy app via terminal on my Mac, however when exported on Android it instantly crashes if some special characters are inserted (à, é...)

Putting `#encoding = <UTF-8>` doesn't solve the problem, neither does compiling with buildozer.

The special characters are REALLY needed, because the app analyses a webpage source code...

Thanks !

Comment: Is this inserted as in entered by a user in the textinput? Could you post an example where this happens?

Comment: Everywhere - for example, I downloaded the compass exemple given by Kivy. It runs perfectly on android using the launcher. I add ' a = "a" ' in the code, it still works. I add ' a = "à" ' : it crashes

Comment: I managed to delete all the special characters, but I'm still importing a text from a URL that has some in it...
        response = s.post('<website>', data=form)
        reponse = str(str(response.text).encode('utf-8'))
So it crashes right before the conversion I guess...